Setup Selenium Grid 4 with Appium docker container
I want to setup Selenium Grid 4 with appium docker file. Taken reference from link  and setup Selenium grid 4 with appium server and emulator running in local machine.
Now we want to have appium server and emulator in separate docker container instead of running in local machine
Already setup the Selenium Grid 4, appium server and emulator in local machine to explain more image is added Already completed setup in local machine
Added a image to explain more what i want to achieve
This is what is required
Able to setup Selenium Grid 4 and appium server on local machine however, Now we want to have appium server and emulator in separate docker container instead of running in local machine
